# Angular, PHP con MYSQL error

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs-2.0, http

Tengo un problema cuando intento recuperar el objecto JSON retornado por el script PHP.

Cuando el servidor retorna el objecto JSON y recupero el objecto en Angular obtengo un error.

Si elimino del código la conversión res.json(), el error no aparece y el servidor no retorna nada.

> ```
> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
> at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
> at Response.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Body.json
>
> (http.es5.js:797)
> at SafeSubscriber._next (list-alunos.component.ts:14)
> at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub
>
> (Subscriber.js:238)
> at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>
> (Subscriber.js:185)
> at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>
> (Subscriber.js:125)
> at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>
> (Subscriber.js:89)
> at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
> at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>
> (zone.js:424)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
> ```

Tengo un servicio que recuperar la información y un componente que utiliza este servicio:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ApiHttpDaoService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getListStudents() {
        return this.http.get("http://localhost/obtener_alunos.php");
    }
}
```

Este es el componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiHttpDaoService } from '../../services/api-http-dao.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-list-alunos',
    templateUrl: './list-alunos.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list-alunos.component.css']
})
export class ListAlunosComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private service: ApiHttpDaoService) {
        this.service.getListStudents().subscribe(
            res => console.log(res.json())
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Y este es el código PHP que retorna el objecto JSON:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    require("conectar_mysql.php");

    $vec_res = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM alunos");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($vec_res, array('nome' => $row['nome'], 'idade' => 
            $row['idade'], 'morada' => $row['morada']));
        }
        echo json_encode($vec_res);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

echo json_encode($vec_res); El json_encode($vec_res) no me está devolviendo nada.

Em cambio si construyo el json como un string:

```
$jsonObj = "{";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $jsonObj .= '{' . "nome: " . $row['nome'] . ', ' . "idade: " . $row['idade'] . '}' . ', ';
    }
$jsonObj = "}";
```

Y después hago echo $jsonObj; aparece el string JSON en la network en preview como un string.

Cambie el codigo para esto con el json_enconde no retorna nada: Con el nuevo codigo retorna la string

```
[{nome: Reynier Lima T�llez, idade: 28}, {nome: Jo�o Matos, idade: 30}, 
 {nome: Joana Bonan�a, idade: 33}]

<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');   
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    require("conectar_mysql.php");

    $vec_res = array();
    $jsonObj = "[";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM alunos");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $jsonObj .= '{' . "nome: " . $row['nome'] . ', ' . "idade: " . 
            $row['idade'] . '}' . ', ';
        }

        $jsonObj = substr($jsonObj, 0, strlen($jsonObj) - 2);
        echo $jsonObj . ']';
}

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Ahora en la respuesta me llega el objecto pero en el controlador si hago console.log(res._body) me dice que no existe la propriedad "_body".

[image: response]

```
constructor(private service: ApiHttpDaoService) {
    this.service.getListStudents().subscribe(
        res => console.log(res._body)
    ); 
}

C:/Users/Reynier/Documents/angular-projects/project/src/pages/list-
alunos/list-alunos.component.ts (14,36): Property '_body' does not exist on 
type 'Response'. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EtwK.png
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el json que retorna PHP.

Comment: ola el problema es que no veo que retorna nada quando hago echo json_encode($vec_res); el echo no tiene nada y si voy a ver en el network no aparece nada. ahora si hago un print de los elementos utilizando un ciclo se ven los elementos guardados en el vector. Pero solo con el json_encode($vec_res); no me esta a retornar nada

Comment: `Cuando el servidor retorna el objecto JSON y recupero el objecto en Angular Obtengo un error.` = en esta línea `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0` ¿tienes manera de saber qué hay allí?, Si te es posible, intenta devolver el JSON como string a ver que devuelve...

Comment: Si hago esto $jsonObj = "{";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $jsonObj .= '{' . "nome: " . $row['nome'] . ', ' . "idade: " . $row['idade'] . '}' . ', ';
}

$jsonObj .= "}";
echo $jsonObj     // Despues retorno con el echo la variable con el JSON creado como uma string aparece en la respuesta en el network. Pero no entiendo porque con el json_enconde no envia nada.

Comment: Reyner, por favor agrega esa información (y el json que muestra el $echo) en tu pregunta, dale click en [edit].  Los comentarios son temporales.

Comment: @Shaz [discusión relevante](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2515/83).

Comment: @ReynierTéllez, por un lado necesitaríamos que agregues en tu pregunta el resultado de hacer `var_dump($vec_res)`. Y por otro lado, la forma en que construyes el `JSON`, esta mal; la sintaxis correcta debería ser `[{"prop1": "valor1", "prop2": "valor2"},{"prop1": "valor1", "prop2": "valor2"},..]`